# In 2D CFTs what are the possible forms of correlation functions

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

I am following Sylvain Ribault's lectures on 2D CFT (https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09523) in which he lays out 2D CFTs in an axiomatic format.

In a CFT we assert (as an axiom) that there is a correspondence between an algebra of operators $\mathcal{A}$ defined on the Riemann sphere and the states in a representation of the Virasoro algebra $\mathcal{H}_V$. We also define a linear function

$$f:\mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{C},$$

which we call the correlation function. I know that the operators in $\mathcal{A}$ are linear operators in some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_\mathcal{A}$ (which I don't think I need to take to be $\mathcal{H}_V$). This tells me that the correlation function must be of the form

$$f(A) = \langle v|A|w \rangle$$

for some vectors $|v \rangle , |w \rangle \in \mathcal{H}_\mathcal{A}$. Is it true that there is some consequence of the 2D CFT axioms which tells me that I can express it in the form

$$f(A) = \langle v|A|v \rangle,$$

i.e. that its an actual expectation value as in regular quantum theory?

Comment: Are you implying that in a usual quantum theory one can only consider $\langle v | A | v \rangle$ rather then the more general $\langle v | A | w \rangle$?

Comment: @MannyC we do consider these sorts of objects, but I'm pretty sure that in QFT when we say correlation function we mean vacuum expectation value i.e. $\langle V \rangle$ is really $\langle \Omega | V | \Omega \rangle$ where $| \Omega \rangle$ is the vacuum

Comment: Is there any reason you expect the axioms to have that consequence? Just because we are *physically* usually interested in the case where $\lvert v\rangle = \lvert w\rangle$, mathematicians usually do not restrict such axiomatics until it is necessary to prove some desirable property.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I dont know that it must be so, but it would make my life much easier. For example the two point functions then become a statement about orthonormalization of $L_0$ eigenstates, Computing OPE coefficients is then a matter of finding the matrix elements of quasi primary operators in my $L_0$ eigenbasis... 

Again, I dont know this to be true but I'm sorta hoping that it is

Comment: I don't about the axioms, but the usual assumption is that you can always get to any state $|w\rangle$ by applying some operator to $|v\rangle$. So the $v$ expectation value of all operators also gives you information on the off-diagonal correlation functions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my lectures the space of states is not assumed to be a Hilbert space, i.e. to have a positive definite scalar product. Actually it is not assumed to have a scalar product at all. So you cannot write $\langle v|$ and the short answer to your question is no.

Actually you do not need a scalar product for computing OPEs or anything else. Nevertheless, you can add the extra axiom that there is a scalar product such that $L_n^\dagger = L_{-n}$, and use it for your computations. Adding this axiom forces the central charge and conformal dimensions to be real, so it is a restriction on the CFTs that you can consider.